# How to use custom HTML markup in woocommerce

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce

I've got a little trouble with a woocommerce. I must use custom HTML markup in woocommerce templates. I have searched about hooks and actions, but i can't find right way to start develop new theme.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried ?

Comment: Sure: first, like i understand, i must to disable hooks, that i need to edit:/* product category view */
//disable link
remove_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10);

Comment: Also i tried to copy/paste woocommerce functions to template files, but does not right. Finally i've created question here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use woocemerce templates. You add woocomerce directory in your theme with your own templates inside them. It works in a similar way a child theme does.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: Yes, i know about this feature, but i also don't understand. Let me show example: i've created woocommerce folder with files needed to edit from plugin folder, right? Inside, for example, content-product.php i must to remove everything and put my html code? If yes, what about dynamic tags like price, title, etc..?

Comment: Your html code with woo's dinamic call. Check how they've done it. So where you need to display price just add code they used to display price. You have to code everything in, its not like its going to magically link all the  stuff on its own :)